# Wait for most recent route match in Cypress test

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cypress

I am testing a form wizard application with Cypress which makes a number of API calls that I cannot stub. Nearly all of them resolve instantly or are inconsequential to the flow but there are a few that outlast the timeout which I need to wait for. Consider the following:

```
cy.route('api/**').as('api');

request('api/api-1');
doSomething();
cy.wait('@api'); // works as expected.

request('api/api-2'); // resolves async, timing doesn't matter, don't need to wait
doSomething();

request('api/api-3');
doSomething();
cy.wait('@api'); // will resolve immediately for api/api-2 instead of api/api-3.
```

I'd prefer not to have to alias every specific API call that needs a wait separately. The requests that aren't awaited in the test happen in the background on the page so I cannot simply add waits after each one.

TLDR; Is there a way to target the most recent request that matches a given route alias with wait rather than resolving them sequentially off of a queue?

Comment: You can use multiple `cy.route()`'s with different aliases and then use `cy.get()` that will wait only if the response isn't ready.

Comment: I ended up creating routes for every possible endpoint that needs awaited in a test, leaving this open because I believe this should be doable.